# If $X$ is separable then so is $B_X.$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces

> Let $X$ be a separable normed linear space. Then show that $B_X = \{x \in X\ |\ \|x\| = 1\}$ is also separable.

Since $X$ is separable it has a countable dense subset. Let $D = \{x_n\ |\ n \in \Bbb N \}$ be a countable dense subset of $X.$ WLOG we may assume that $0 \not\in D$ for otherwise we could take $D \setminus \{0\}$ which continues to be dense in $X.$ Then I guess that $D' = \left \{\frac {x_n} {\|x_n\|}\ \bigg |\ n \in \Bbb N \right \}$ is a dense subset of $B_X.$ Let $y \in X$ with $\|y\| = 1.$ Let us choose $\varepsilon \gt 0$ arbitrarily. Then I need to show that $B(y,\varepsilon)$ intersects $D'.$ If $y = x_n$ then we are through. If not then there exists a sequence $\{x_{k_n}\}_{n \geq 1}$ in $D$ converging to $y.$ Since norm is a continuous function it follows that $\|x_{k_n}\| \to \|y\| = 1$ as $n \to \infty.$ But this shows that $\frac {x_{k_n}} {\|x_{k_n}\|} \to y$ as $n \to \infty,$ proving that $D'$ is dense in $B_X.$

Does my proof make sense? Can anybody plaese check my argument above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is correct, but it is generally true that any subspace of a separable metric space is separable.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes it's correct. Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Then $X$ is separable iff it is second countable i.e. it has countable open base. So if we take a countable open base $\{B_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of $X$ then for any subspace $Y$ of $X$ the collection $\{B_n \cap Y\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ will be a countable open base of $Y.$ Hence any subspace of $X$ would be second countable and hence separable as well. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

A shorter proof could be : If $X$ is metric and separable then has a countable basis. Any subspace of a countable basis space is countable basis (take the trace on the subspace), and in the end recall that if a space has a countable basis is separable.